# AdMob not showing test ads: Error Code 3 - "No ad config."

Tags: android, admob

I'm creating a project with the newest admob version, and I'm using admob test ids for testing ads:

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

```
App id --- ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
Banner --- ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
Interstitial --- ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712
```

Something isn't work properly, because both formats are giving me error:

```
onAdFailedToLoad() error code: 3 - No ad config.
onAdFailedToLoad() error code: 3 - No ad config.
```

How can I display test ads? why the official test ids doesn't works? I'm testing in emulator with android 13 and in real Pixel XL device with android 10. Same problem in both.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure if this is a definitive solution or someone will post something better in the future, but I achieved to see test ads signing the apk with release key and using the test ids from google, then installing that signed apk on a real device.

This is extremely frustrating, test ads should be displayed in android studio when simulating...